# Object does not appear in render view but appears in all other views

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

After updating to Blender 2.79, I had to fix my rig by using the following fix: ['LIB ERROR: object lost from scene' error when opening file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78200/lib-error-object-lost-from-scene-error-when-opening-file)

But after doing that the object does not appear in render! It is enabled for rendering but it does not appear in render view or when rendering, but it does appear in solid, textured and material views. Can anyone help please? I am using Cycles Render.

Comment: Are the objects in a layer that is being rendered?

Comment: I think the layer is being rendered. How can I make sure? There are only three objects in the scene: the camera, the lamp, and the object that is not being rendered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out: The Diffuse BSDF node was linked to Volume in the output, instead of to Surface.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that "Camera" is enabled under the Cycles settings in your object, otherwise your object cannot be seen by the camera.

[image]

Comment: Camera is already enabled in Cycles settings